# Google AppEngine Push Task Queues: Is this the tasks last retry?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I use Google AppEngines Task Queues.

How can I figure out, if the task thats called is called for the last time (after n fails/retries)?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation that you linked to, it looks like you can get the number of retries for the current task by looking at the `X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount` HTTP header.

If you know the `task_retry_limit`, you'll know if it's being called for the last time.